# Definitive reference for Google Maps Placemark object

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding

I am using the following method to reverse geocode a google maps latlng:

```
[GClientGeocoder.getLocations(address:String, callback:function)][1]
```

Which states as follows:

As this method requires a call to a Google server, you must also pass a callback method to handle the response. This response will contain a Status code, and if successful, one or more  Placemark objects.

Can anyone point me to a definitive reference of what a Placemark object is as it seems to return different attributes for different locations. e.g. sometimes I get a ThoroughfareName and others an AddressLine. I would like to understand if I will always get one or other of them and whether they are interchangeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#Geocoding_Structured) is from the Google Maps API documentation, and contains a pretty straightforward explanation of what a **Placemark** object is.

However, the part you probably want to focus on is where it states what format Google uses for the **AddressDetails** object in a **Placemark**, which is **xAL (eXtensible Address Language)**.  There is a link to the spec there, which leads to a downloadable schema (xsd file), which essentially defines the entire format.  A word of warning:  the spec is pretty extensive, but you may not need to worry about a great deal of it for your project.

EDIT:
Apologies for not being allowed to add links to the relevant pages for you.

Comment: Thanks, this is more or less what I was looking for. I was looking at the API reference and would have expected a link from there. xAL seems to be pretty flexible and the answer is in the way google populates it, which is probably not available anywhere. I shall probably keep things simple and go with the assumption that thoroughfareName and addressLine are interchangable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to hunt for it, but Google does in fact have [some documentation about Placemarks](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html#ReverseGeocoding) hidden away.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the Placemark object do vary based on the data available.  I found the best way to work out what I was getting back was to [use](http://www.cannonade.net/geo.php?test=geo1) JSON.stringify to examine the response (for debugging):

```
function onGeocode (resp)
{
    document.getElementById("cd_output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify (resp);
}
```

This gave me the following results when I GeoCoded an address in Sydney, Australia:

```
Placemark
{
    id, address, 
    AddressDetails
    {
        Country, CountryNameCode, CountryName, 
        AdministrativeArea
        {
            AdministrativeAreaName, 
            Locality
            {
                LocalityName
                Thoroughfare { ThoroughfareName }
                PostalCode { PostalCodeNumber }
            }
        }
    }
    Accuracy,
    ExtendedData
    {
        LatLonBox { north,south,east,west }
        Point { coordinates }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've found using firebug to be a decent way of viewing the results too.